# Best way to backup app data with google drive?

Tags: android, sqlite, google-drive-android-api, android-backup-service

So I have an app that I've written that's using sqlite (so has a db in the data folder) and about 12-50MBs worth of server and user generated content. I need to automatically back this up for the users in such a way that when they move devices/get new devices all their changes and content auto-magically come over with them. Now if it keeps all the current devices synced together that's bonus, but *not* a requirement.

**What is the best way to do this?**

I've looked at backup agent, but that seems to be only semi-supported on some devices and looks like if you were going to from say a verizon device to a say sprint device you would just lose everything (but I may be misunderstanding how it works).

I've also been looking at google drive through play services, but despite the docs making it sound like I could just get access to the appFolder and just move/store everything there, in practice I can't seem to find a simple way to do this. Do I really have to loop over every single file manually uploading it? I can do this if this is the best solution, but I thought before I put 12-15hours of work into it it would be best to ask here if that's my best solution.

Thanks for any input!

**TL;DR**

What's the simplest cloud backup solution that isn't network dependent and doesn't require anything more then a google account for the end user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of the best approach is to use Android Backup Service
check from [here](http://developer.android.com/google/backup/index.html)

Comment: That's what I meant by "backup agent". But on second read it does say: `The Android Backup Service offered by Google provides a backup transport on most devices that include Google Play Store and backs up your app data to Google servers.` I'll play with it and see, because that looks to be the easiest solution for sure.